# creating a dfm of words with letters

Tags: r, sapply, quanteda, dfm

I am trying to create a dfm of letters from strings. I am facing issues when the dfm is unable to pick on can create features for punctuations such as "/" "-" "." or '.

```
require(quanteda)
dict = c('a','b','c','d','e','f','/',".",'-',"'")
dict <- quanteda::dictionary(sapply(dict, list))

x<-c("cab","baa", "a/de-d/f","ad")
x<-sapply(x, function(x) strsplit(x,"")[[1]])
x<-sapply(x, function(x) paste(x, collapse = " "))

mat <- dfm(x, dictionary = dict, valuetype = "regex")
mat <- as.matrix(mat)
mat
```

1. For "a/de-d/f", I want to capture the  letters "/" "-" too
2. Why is the "." feature acting as a rowsum. How can I keep it as individual feature?

Comment: Like `tokens <- tokenize(x, what = "character"); mat <- dfm(tokens, dictionary = dict, valuetype = "fixed")`? In a regular expression ("regex"), `.` stands for any character.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as @lukeA points out in a comment) is that your `valuetype` is using the wrong pattern match.  You are using a regular expression where the `.` stands for any character, and hence here is getting you a total (what you call a rowsum).

Let's first look at `x`, which will be tokenised on the whitespace by `dfm()`, so that each character becomes a token.

```
x
#        cab               baa          a/de-d/f                ad 
#    "c a b"           "b a a" "a / d e - d / f"             "a d"
```

To answer (2) first, you are getting the following with a "regex" match:

```
dfm(x, dictionary = dict, valuetype = "regex", verbose = FALSE)
## Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 10 features.
## 4 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##           features
## docs       a b c d e f / . - '
##   cab      1 1 1 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
##   baa      2 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
##   a/de-d/f 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 5 0 0
##   ad       1 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 0
```

That's close, but does not answer (1).  To solve that, you need to alter the default tokenisation behaviour by `dfm()` so that it does not remove punctuation.

```
dfm(x, dictionary = dict, valuetype = "fixed", removePunct = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)
## Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 10 features.
## 4 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##           features
## docs       a b c d e f / . - '
##   cab      1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
##   baa      2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
##   a/de-d/f 1 0 0 2 1 1 2 0 1 0
##   ad       1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

and now the `/` and `-` are being counted.  The `.` and `'` remain present as features because they were dictionary keys, but have a zero count for every document.

Comment: Thanks. I already got it fixed with just `valuetype = "fixed"` argument and without removPunct. I guess it doesnt matter as It was catching on all punctuations anyway.